# Отличаются CSS позиции текста на разных мониторах с одинаковым разрешением

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

Писал CSS код для текста, который должен был располагаться ровно в div элементе, но столкнулся с проблемой. Проверяю страничку на двух мониторах. В одном случае текст выходит за рамки div, во втором не выходит, хотя div и все остальные размеры совпадают.
[image: Текст выходит за рамки div][image: Текст не выходит за рамки div].
Оба монитора 16:9, 1920:1080, отличаются только герцовкой 60 и 75, диагональю 15.6 и 27(здесь текст вмещается).

Код CSS:

```
  #startScreen{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  position:fixed;
}


#startGreetings{
  background: floralwhite;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}

.welcomeLetters{
  font-size: 150px;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Код HTML, если нужен

```
  <div id="startScreen">
    <div id="startGreetings">
      <h1 class="welcomeLetters" id="W">W</h1>
      <h1 class="welcomeLetters" id="E1">E</h1>
      <h1 class="welcomeLetters" id="L">L</h1>
      <h1 class="welcomeLetters" id="C">C</h1>
      <h1 class="welcomeLetters" id="O">O</h1>
      <h1 class="welcomeLetters" id="M">M</h1>
      <h1 class="welcomeLetters" id="E2">E</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Использовать размер букв в пикселях мягко говоря дурной тон, хотя по раззметке слова welcome можно увидеть что вы новичок.   Замените font-size: не в px, а в em или rem.

Comment: Это не поможет решить проблему. Суть в том что я пробовал практически всё, но просто пиксели были последние. А в оправдание к разметке, хочу сказать что это для анимации, мол слово появляется по буке, и пропадает, но за советы большое спасибо, вы правы, я новичок))

Comment: У вас наверняка в системе стоит разный масштаб текста для разных мониторов.  Для здоровенного 27" - 100%, а для пендюрки (спорю, что вы к ноуту внешник подключили, у самого так =) ) - 125%, например. Лезьте в настройки винды, или что у вас там...

Comment: @Инквизитор Да, это помогло))) Но не подскажете, можно ли в самом коде эту ситуацию предусмотреть, с помощью js или css? Я исправил это у себе, но условно есть пользователи использующие масштаб 100% и т.д.

Comment: @n33t можно установить user-scalable=no и добавить целиком этот тег <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">, но учтите, что отмена масштабирования - проблема доступности контента.

Comment: @highpassion Я так понимаю использовать шрифт для подобной анимации не лучшая идея, правильно? Если я планировал растянуть его на весь экран(Повторюсь, слово welcome появляется по букве и пропадает).

Comment: можете попробовать привязаться к размеру окна (не экрана, а именно окна браузера, точнее, вьюпорта) с помощью единиц измерения vw / vh

Comment: @n33t вы можете использовать шрифт, но лучше используйте элемент span для таких целей, по семантике так правильнее.

Comment: @Инквизитор Да, теперь всё работает так как я и хотел. Спасибо вам большое <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить вычисление размеров контента и сравните отображение.

```
<script>
  if (window.devicePixelRatio !== 1) {    
        var dpt = window.devicePixelRatio;
        var widthM = window.screen.width * dpt;
        var widthH = window.screen.height * dpt;
        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=' + widthM+ ', height=' + widthH + '">');  
  }
</script>
```